# find indices of sorted array such that a[i]+a[j]=x

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

This is an interview question: given an `integer x` and a `sorted array a[] of N distinct integers`, design a `linear-time algorithm` to determine if there exists two distinct indices i and j such that `a[i] + a[j] == x`. No auxiliary storage is allowed.
I have implemented this in `Java`. but my current run time is `O(nlogn)` because I do a `binarySearch` on `each iteration`. so it is not strictly `linear`. I am wondering if there exists a `linear time solution` for this problem. If so, some pointers on it could be helpful.

Thanks.

```
public class SumArrayIndex {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        sumSortedArray(arr, 4);
        System.out.println();
        sumSortedArray(arr, 19);
        System.out.println();
        sumSortedArray(arr, 100);

    }

    public static void sumSortedArray(int[] arr, int sum){
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            int temp=Arrays.binarySearch(arr, sum-arr[i]);
            if (temp>0 && temp!=i){
                System.out.printf("The two indices are %s and %s%n ",i,temp);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("The sum:%s cannot be formed with given array:%s",sum,Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: Start two pointers, one at either end of the array.  Check their sum.  If it's too small, move the lesser pointer up one space.  If it's too big, move the greater pointer down one space in the array.  If the pointers meet each other and you haven't found something that works, nothing will work.

Comment: are all the integers positive?

Comment: @Claudiu: yes they are positive

Comment: @leif: good shout, I believe this works.
On a variant of this problem, if the array is not (necessarily) sorted and aux storage is allowed, dumping them all to a hash table and instead of doing a binary search - do a hash table query gives linear solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @leif in the comment, start from the begin and end of `array`, move the begin index or end index if the sum is greater or smaller. you should find a begin and end `index` such that their values equal `sum`. if not, you there exists no such indices. something on this line below. I have not tested this code and assuming positive integers

The code below is self explanatory:

```
public static void sumSortedArray2(int[] arr, int sum){
        boolean found=false;
        int max=arr.length-1;
        int min=0;
        while (min<max){
            if(arr[min]+arr[max]<sum)
                min++;
          else if (arr[min]+arr[max]>sum)
                max--;
          else {
              found =true;
              break;
          }
    }
    if (found){
        System.out.printf("The two indices are %s and %s%n ",min,max);
    }
    else {
        System.out.printf("The sum:%s cannot be formed with given array:%s",sum,Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your algorithm to be linear time, with these observations:

1. Without losing the generality, you can say that `i` and `j` are such that `arr[i]<arr[j]`. Proof: if that is not so, you can swap `i` and `j`.
2. Considering that you started the search at the beginning, when you search for `sum-arr[i]`, you can always search to the right of index `i`; if `sum-arr[i] < arr[i]`, you know that there is no answer, because `j` would be to the left of `i`
3. If your previous search for `sum-arr[i]` has ended at index `k` without yielding a result, your next search can go between indexes `i` and `k`.
4. You do not need to search for `sum-arr[i]` using a binary search: you can do a linear search from the back, and keep the point `k` where `arr[k] < sum-arr[i]` as your next starting point.

This lets you build an algorithm that examines each item exactly once.

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm you provided. I am wondering how different it is from the solution posted below. I think they are almost the same...or my understanding is wrong then.

Comment: @eagertoLearn user1988876 and I posted the same algorithm from two different perspectives - I described the math behind the `O(n)`, while he provided an `O(n)` implementation in code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight +1 for the explanation. I just cannot explain in simple terms as you did!!!. That obviously the reason for your high reputations I guess

Comment: +1, very beautiful explanation of how to do the transition from the original solution the the O(n) one.